# Reading the Heap information about another application

Tags: android

I'm developing a system service that monitors application and I want to read Heap information of other applications.

I know that inside an application I can do something like this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long freeMem = runtime.freeMemory();
long totalMem = runtime.totalMemory();
long maxMem = runtime.maxMemory();
```

and I can retrieve the pid of running applications.

But, is there any way in which I can get the Runtime instance of a specific process, given its pid, or in which I can get Heap information from outside the process?